# Amadeus Hotel Booking returns null through Amadeus API Response returns properly

Tags: amadeus

```
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();

    HotelBooking[] hotelBook=null;

    try {
        String jsonInString=mapper.writeValueAsString(hotelBookRequestDTO);         

        hotelBook=amadeus.booking.hotelBookings.post(jsonInString);
       }
```

The above hotel booking returns null when calling the API with the Java SDK 4.0. I debugged the Amadeus SDK, it returns the Response Object properly but the returned method doesn't properly convert the Response object to HotelBooking[].

```
  public HotelBooking[] post(String body)throws ResponseException{
 Response response = client.post("/v1/booking/hotel-bookings", body);
    return (HotelBooking[]) Resource.fromArray(response, HotelBooking[].class);

}
```

Can some one from the Amadeus development team can help on this issue?

Comment: It might be better to contact the supplier directly.

Answer (score 1):

We deployed the new version 4.0.1 of [Amadeus Java SDK](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-java) which fixes the issue. Indeed there was a bug related to the resource HotelBooking.java, where the AssociatedRecord returned by the Hotel Booking API should be an object array instead of object.